# Deleting/destroying button on python 3.4 that was made in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, widget, python-3.3

I'm trying to destroy a button I click that was made in a for loop. Tried making the making the button go into a list, then using the list to delete, but I can't seem to make it work.

Here's the code:

```
root = Tk()

word_list = ["APPLE", "PEAR", "BANANA"]

word = word_list [random.randint(0,2)]

abc = '_ ' * len(word)
print (word)
lives = 0

guessed_letters = []

buttons = []

#Function
def click_1 (key):
    buttons.append(key)
    print (buttons)
    if key in word:
        guessed_letters.append(key)
        abc = ''.join([key if key in guessed_letters else "_ " for key in word])
        if abc == word:
            letters_label.config(text="You win!")
            raise SystemExit
        letters_label.config(text=abc)
        key_1 = buttons.index(key)
        buttons[key_1].destroy(END)
    else:
        guessed_letters.append(key)
        global lives
        lives += 1
        hangman_label.config(text=hangman_pics[lives])
        if lives == 6:
            letters_label.config(text="You lose...")
            lives -= 1
            raise SystemExit





#Frames
hangman_frame = Frame(root)
hangman_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N)
letter_frame = Frame(root)
letter_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=S)

#Label
letters_label = Label(hangman_frame, text=abc)
letters_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

hangman_label = Label(hangman_frame, text=hangman_pics[lives])
hangman_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)



#Buttons
r = c = 0
for letter in string.ascii_uppercase:
    Button(letter_frame, text=letter, command=functools.partial(click_1, letter)).grid(row=r, column=c, sticky=W)
    c += 1
    if c > 12:
        c = 0
        r += 1
```

(Sorry for block, think all is relevant)

Can anyone see anything wrong? I have tried many different things, all which do not work. The specific error message for this code is:

```
['A']
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/alexeacott/Desktop/Hangman.py", line 85, in click_1
    buttons[key_1].destroy(END)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'destroy'
```

And if I change the 
    .destroy()
to 
.grid.forget
the error says:

```
AttributeError: 'str object has no attribute 'grid'
```

How do I not make it a 'str'? How do I get my code working?!

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

as per the suggestion:

```
#Buttons
r = c = 0
for letter in string.ascii_uppercase:
    c += 1
    my_button = Button(letter_frame, text=letter).grid(row=r, column=c, sticky=W)
    my_button.configure(command=functools.partial(click_1, letter, my_button)
    if c > 12:
        c = 0
        r += 1
```

this says that there is a syntax error on the colon of the line:

```
if c > 12:
```

Comment: `my_button.configure(...(...)` needs a closing `)`.  Hence SyntaxError detected on neXt line.  Detecting missing closer on next line is typical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the statement where you create the button:

```
Button(letter_frame, text=letter, command=functools.partial(click_1, letter)).grid(row=r, column=c, sticky=W)
```

you are passing `letter` as parameter to `click_1(key)`. `letter` is a `str`. That is where the problem is.

What you want to do is, pass the button itself as another parameter to it. You can do this only after the button has been created, like this:

```
my_button = Button(letter_frame, text=letter)
my_button.configure(command=functools.partial(click_1, letter, my_button))
my_button.grid(row=r, column=c, sticky=W)
```

and modify the `click_1` method to take the button as one of its params like so:

```
#Function
def click_1 (key, button):
    buttons.append(button)
    # ...
```

***Update:***

You might have to modify your `click_1` method to get the button using `key`. One simple change you can do to make this work is have `buttons` as an `OrderedDict` instead of a list. `OrderedDict` is just a `dict` which remembers order of its items like a `list` would. So your modified method would look like:

```
from collections import OrderedDict()
buttons = OrderedDict()        

#Function
def click_1 (key, button):
    buttons[key] = button
    print (buttons)
    if key in word:
        guessed_letters.append(key)
        abc = ''.join([key if key in guessed_letters else "_ " for key in word])
        if abc == word:
            letters_label.config(text="You win!")
            raise SystemExit
        letters_label.config(text=abc)
        #key_1 = buttons.index(key) # REMOVE this
        #buttons[key_1].destroy(END) # REMOVE this
        #Do this instead:
        buttons[key].destroy(END)
    else:
        guessed_letters.append(key)
        global lives
        lives += 1
        hangman_label.config(text=hangman_pics[lives])
        if lives == 6:
            letters_label.config(text="You lose...")
            lives -= 1
            raise SystemExit
```

Hope that was useful.

Comment: Doing what you have suggested has thrown up a lot of syntax errors. Check my edit to see if I have done it right. Thanks

Comment: I still get the syntax error when making my buttons. I have described in my edit. Thanks

Comment: You missed a brace '(' at the end of that line: `my_button.configure(command=functools.partial(click_1, letter, my_button)`. That should be `my_button.configure(command=functools.partial(click_1, letter, my_button))`

Comment: Got a bit further now that I fixed that! However this:
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'configure'
came up, and on my gui, only the A button appeared. Thanks for all the help so far - learnt a lot already!

Comment: Right my bad. I have updated my answer with the correction in that block. We were assigning the result of `grid()`method to `my_button`. I fixed that in my answer.